# trigger event from another form

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys i have this code in my `ViewProductsInventory`(which is called from my `MainForm` by `ShowDialog`):

```
 Private Sub ViewProductsInventory_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Tb_inventory_datesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventorySysDataSet.tb_inventory_dates)
    Dim inventory_date As Date
    inventory_date = Me.cboInventoryDate.Text

End Sub


Public Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim inventory_date As String
    inventory_date = Me.cboInventoryDate.Text

    'this part populates my datagridview1
    Me.SP_GetInventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventorySysDataSet.SP_GetInventory, inventory_date)
End Sub
```

upon clicking the editbutton will execute `EditForm.ShowDialog()`

and in my EditForm the record will be updated, after which will trigger `ViewProductsInventory.btnSearch_Click( ViewProductsInventory.btnSearch, EventArgs.Empty)`

and then the error "Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid" occurs.

I tried `Msgbox(Me.cboInventoryDate.Text)` and returns nothing. I'm assuming that my `cboInventoryDate` is not being populated at this time therefore when `btnSearch_Click` is triggered it receives nothing.

how can i fix this? kindly assist me please. TIA!

Comment: Where is cboInventoryDate located? MainForm, ViewProductsInventory or EditForm. And how are you populating it?

Comment: .It is located in ViewProductsInventory. It is populated by this > Me.Tb_inventory_datesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventorySysDataSet.tb_inventory_dates)

Comment: How many records are being returned to your ComboBox and how are you selecting the one you want?

Comment: .it depends on how many will be returned from the database. I have created a tableadapter to fill the combobox with all of the dates existing in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your `btnSearch_Click` Event:

```
If Me.cboInventoryDate.Items.Count > 0 then
    Me.cboInventoryDate.SelectedIndex = 0
    inventory_date = Me.cboInventoryDate.Text

    'this part populates my datagridview1  
    Me.SP_GetInventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventorySysDataSet.SP_GetInventory, inventory_date)

End If
```

Comment: .this won't work.. this will affect the natural behavior of the button. let's say you click the button to search for the records of a certain date, the line Me.cboInventoryDate.SelectedIndex = 0 will trigger a selection change to the cboInventoryDate thus disabling you to select different dates.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Try using the Items.Count method to determine wether or not the control has data. You may have to create another method in your program and call it from your EditForm then wait till the ComboBox gets filled before calling the Click event.